# Is it safe and secure to use PHP-7 on FreeBSD?

Tags: php, security, freebsd

I'm new to FreeBSD.

My production server is running PHP-5.6. Even now, 2 years after php-7 is released. When half of the composer packages require php-7 and even Laravel 5.6 requires php-7.1.3... It is slowing me as a developer down and keeping me disappointed.

The problems is - It was never declared that it is "safe and secure" to use PHP-7 on FreeBSD. The default PHP version on FreeBSD is 5.6.

HELP

I know there are ways to install PHP-7 on FreeBSD. I know there are Ports that allow build PHP-7 from source and even PHP-extensions are available there in the ports package manager.

However I cannot find a proof for my sysadmin to persuade hit that it is safe and secure to use latest versions of PHP on FreeBSD.

Where can I find the proof like this? What is going on there in FreeBSD world?

Comment: Yes, it's secure. It sounds like FreeBSD has a package manager and probably likes to keep "compatibility" with everything, but all you need is the installation. PHP 5.6 will [EOL on Jan 1, 2019](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: Thank you, it is really valuable link in my situation.

Comment: What are you talking about? [PHP 7.2 is available in Ports under php72 prefix!](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=php72&stype=all&sektion=all) If it's in the official ports, it's safe and secure.

Comment: Good point, Alex.

Answer (score 1):

[FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) is a very reliable and secure OS but depends on many factors to make this even more secure/safe.

A programing language at the end could be seen as the interface/gateway to upload you malicious code and in some cases try to exploit some vulnerabilities in it.

You could harden more the operating system for example, if you allow `executable` files in `/tmp` you could try to upload this [exploit](https://github.com/nbari/freebsd/blob/master/exploits/zeroday/exploit.sh) and based on the version maybe you succeed, one way to mitigate this could be to just remove `nosuid,noexec` on `/tmp`:

On normal UFS:

```
/dev/da0xx      /tmp        ufs     rw,noexec,nosuid 2
```

Using [tmpfs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tmpfs):

```
tmpfs           /tmp        tmpfs   rw,nosuid,noexec,mode=01777 0   0
```

Or in [ZFS](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/zfs.html):

```
zfs set setuid=off tank/tmp
zfs set exec=off tank/tmp
```

Going further you could use [jails](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html) (personally I prefer them) since even if an exploit suceed it will be contained within the jail and would not affect the main host.

These are some of the things you can do at OS level, but also you may need to configure fine tune your programing language, in php things like [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), etc may help.

Comment: I really like the first sentence.